# Make Simple Membership cookies more secure

Tags: asp.net, cookies, webmatrix

ASP.net [Web Pages](http://www.asp.net/web-pages) stack comes with Simple Membership, of which the best explanation is Matthew Osborn's [Using SimpleMembership](http://blog.osbornm.com/archive/2010/07/21/using-simplemembership-with-asp.net-webpages.aspx).  SimpleMembership is a lightweight user/login/membership system which allows a cookie to be used for "remember me" login purposes.  I would like to improve the the security of the cookie by forcing the cookie to be <strike>httpOnly and be</strike> a secure (https only) cookie.  How can I do this?

Update:  @[Darin Dimitrov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29407/darin-dimitrov) pointed out that httpOnly is session only which is not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use a persistent cookie that would mean that the cookie is no longer stored on the client computer which kind of defeats the whole purpose of the *remember me* functionality. `HttpOnly` cookies are stored in the memory of the browser but only for the given session. In order to improve security make sure that the cookie is set with the [*secure*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie.secure.aspx) flag which indicates that this cookie will be transmitted only over an encrypted connection.

Comment: I didn't realize that HttpOnly was just for session cookies.  I will revise the question to be how do I set a SimpleMembership which I didn't create to be a secure cookie?

Comment: I'd also like to note this is not in the spec (a session cookie is one without an expires header set). The purpose of HttpOnly is to not make the cookie availible to JavaScript or other client side scripting. I know this is an old answer, but are you sure browsers do this, and do you know if it is documented anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

If that applies to you, I suggest to have a look at the source code and see how it's done:
http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/9c98c6e9a150#src%2fWebMatrix.WebData%2fWebSecurity.cs

Now that I've checked myself... :) this is how they look as of now:

```
    public static bool Login(string userName, string password, bool persistCookie = false)
    {
        VerifyProvider();
        bool success = Membership.ValidateUser(userName, password);
        if (success)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, persistCookie);
        }
        return success;
    }

    public static void Logout()
    {
        VerifyProvider();
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    }
```

Where Membership provides about the same API as the System.Web.Security.Membersip -- which is actually swapped with WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider at startup.

Basically if you want a custom auth cookie mechanism you've got to implement your own login & logout logic. The web has plenty of samples in that direction.

I hope this helps a bit. 
Good luck! :)